# How to disable the system for a few seconds in java JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I am new in graphics and I try to disable the code for a few seconds (**without the `sleep()` method**)

```
public class MainClass
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("wait");
        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("GET READY");
        p.add(l);
        l.setBounds(0,0,200,200);
        
        // wait here
        
        for(int i = 0;i<2;i++) {
            l.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            // wait here again:)
            f.repaint();
        }
       
        f.add(p);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background, TL;DR

Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  So using things like `Thread.sleep` or loops will not work.

In most cases, the best solution is to make use of a Swing `Timer`, see [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

A `Timer` is a great way to introduce a callback to occur at some point in the future and they can be used to run once or infinitely (until you stop it).

If you need to wait for some operation to complete, it becomes a little more complicated.  In those cases, you should consider making use of [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), which makes it easier to execute functionality off the Event Dispatching Thread (see [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details), but provides functionality to re-sync information back to the EDT.

## Swing `Timer` Example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("Please wait");
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            // This is all just so we can allow the UI to stablise
            // on the screen
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startWaiting();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void startWaiting() {
            if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    timer = null;
                    label.setText("Thanks for waiting");
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }

    }
}
```